# Angular: public variable

Tags: angular

I have shared component named: "user.service.ts"

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
import { User } from '../_models/index';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: Http, private config: AppConfig) { }

    id: number = 0;
    Apt: number = 0;
 }
```

and I have 2 components:

Comp1:

```js
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    styleUrls: ['userrentsettings.component.css'],
})

export class UserRentSettingsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        public userService: UserService);
         }

             
   ReadData(){
             this.userService.id = 10;
             this.userService.Apt = 10;
             }
```

and on second component, I am trying to read it:

```js
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'index.html'
})

export class User2 implements OnInit {


    constructor(
        public userService: UserService);
         }
             
   ReadData(){
      console.log(this.userService.id);
      console.log(this.userService.Apt);
 }
```

also the UserService is configured as provider in the app.module

result on console is "0" - why?

Comment: Where do you call `ReadData()`?

Comment: You should implement `ngOnInit` instead of `ReadData` if you want your method be called when the component is instantiated.

Comment: in ngOnInit, sorry not to put it here, so this is not it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the ReadData method.

```js
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    styleUrls: ['userrentsettings.component.css'],
})

export class UserRentSettingsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public userService: UserService) {
         this.ReadData();
    }

             
   ReadData(){
             this.userService.id = 10;
             this.userService.Apt = 10;
             }
```

Comment: I call the ReadData on ngOnInit, (this is only partial code)

Comment: You may need to provide enough code for us to see what's going on. Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: I created new project just for demo, and there it is working, I will try to find the diff, and post it here, b.t.w maybe it is related to the routing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:
Issue was due to using bootstrap template that was using: a href="/comp2"
instead of using:
[routerLink]="['/comp2']"